# Can I take the argument of a complex number if it's negative, or do I need to add an angle?

Tags: complex-numbers

For instance, let's say we have a complex number $z=1-i$. It's obvious that the modulus of this number is $\sqrt{2}$. Now If I wanna find the argument I would do:

$\varphi=\arctan (\frac{-1}{1})=\arctan (-1)$

Now should I take $\varphi = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\varphi = \frac{7\pi}{4}$? Can I just take whichever one I like, or should I take both?

Answer (score 0):

You can take both, but it does matter what your purpose is. If you want $\arg$ to be a function, you need to decide on a *branch* (here that means decide on a range of values $a\le\arg z<a+2\pi$ or $a<\arg z\le a+2\pi$) where you fix an output range. Then the argument becomes unique and you have a discontinuous function.

Comment: So would it matter if I was finding the complex roots of this number?

Comment: To find *all* the complex (square, cube,…) roots of any number you need to use multiple argument values, to catch all solutions. @downmath